# How does one compute the mean of weekly data by column using R?

Tags: r, xts

I have a data frame of daily data: df with four columns: `Date, A, B, C`
and am trying to get the mean of weekly data by column.
I tried:

```
library(xts)
xdf <- xts(df[ ,-1],as.Date(df$Date))

apply.weekly(xdf,mean)
```

but this gives me the mean of all the columns. I need the weekly means of each column.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First get some data (I'll use a `data.frame` since that's what you're using, but I really suggest you use a time series class for time series objects)

```
getSymbols("SPY", src='yahoo', from='2012-05-01', to='2012-06-15',
           return.class='data.frame')
#"SPY"
```

`apply.weekly` will split the data up by weeks and apply a function to each week. `apply.weekly(SPY, mean)` would calculate the mean of all the data for that week, but you want it to calculate the mean *of each column* for each week.  So, you have to `apply` `mean` to each column

```
apply.weekly(SPY, function(x) apply(x, 2, mean))
#           SPY.Open SPY.High SPY.Low SPY.Close SPY.Volume SPY.Adjusted
#2012-05-04 139.6425 140.4675 138.750  139.3275  149400050     138.6075
#2012-05-11 135.9480 136.9320 135.338  136.2040  173105700     135.5020
#2012-05-18 133.3000 133.9180 132.036  132.1760  229282720     131.4960
#2012-05-25 131.7660 132.6800 130.896  132.2140  176634780     131.5340
#2012-06-01 131.7100 132.8925 130.290  131.2725  191170200     130.5950
#2012-06-08 130.2780 131.3380 129.584  130.8580  175917220     130.1820
#2012-06-15 132.8420 133.7760 131.828  132.8020  184751180     132.2540
```

For reference, `apply.weekly` is a wrapper for `period.apply` so you could also get the above result with

```
period.apply(SPY, endpoints(SPY, "weeks"), FUN=function(x) apply(x, 2, mean))
```

Comment: I have problems installing this.I get an error message:install.packages("xts",repos="http://r-forge.r-project.org")
Warning message:
package ‘xts’ is not available (for R version 2.15.0)

Comment: It turns out that I was getting that output because another package that I had loaded was colliding with xts. So, updating to the dev version of `xts` will not help you.  Sorry.  I will update the post.

Comment: `apply.weekly(SPY, colMeans)` provides the same results and is quite a bit more succinct.